# Equivalent for DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I hope anyone can help me, as I am a beginner in PostgreSQL. I am trying to build a query using Oracle Transparent Gateway to a Postgres database and recover something similar to the output of `all_tab_partitions` in Oracle. Obviously not all fields, but just the basics.

My query in Oracle looks like this ( the list of values is a variable I retrieved in a step before   )

```
SELECT TABLE_OWNER , 
    TABLE_NAME ,
    PARTITION_NAME,
    TABLESPACE_NAME, 
    NVL(NUM_ROWS,0) as NUM_ROWS
    FROM DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS 
WHERE TABLE_OWNER IN ( 'list of values' );
```

I was able to use this query for getting information as kind of `all_tables`.

```
SELECT  upper(a."schemaname")        as OWNER , 
        upper(a."tablename")         as TABLE_NAME, 
        upper(nvl(a."tablespace",'pg_default')) as TABLESPACE_NAME,
        nvl(b."n_live_tup",0) as NUM_ROWS 
FROM 
"pg_tables"@DBLPGDEMO a
join "pg_stat_user_tables"@DBLPGDEMO b 
on a."schemaname" = b."schemaname" and
   a."tablename"  = b."relname" 
where a."schemaname" in ( 'my_list_of_schemas' ) ;
```

I've been looking in Google but I can't find exactly what I am looking for. I have the data of  `pg_tables` and `information_schema.tables` , as well as the statistics from `pg_stat_user_tables`, but not for partitioning.

Does anyone know how can I get this from Postgres ?

Comment: `pg_stat_user_tables` is **not** the equivalent of `all_tables`. That would be `pg_tables`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I use `pg_stat_user_tables` to get the value of the statistics, so I can fill up num_rows with `n_live_tup`. Is this wrong ?